# Where to put a floating progress bar in a multi-step form

Tags: forms, user-behavior, workflow, progress-bar, multi-step

I am doing an interactive form that shows the progress related between filled and not filled inputs. As a result, I have a progress bar that shows how many steps did I filled and how many are missing.

I want to show this progress bar always. So, I decided to make it "position fixed" somewhere in the screen, but I am  a bit confused about where it will be better positioned to be user friendly.

Comment: how is the design of the page? Are all steps in the same page or next page?

Comment: Hello, all steps are in the same page, at the beginning all the groups are hidden, except the first, and each group is shown when the previous is filled.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't mess with convention unless you have to**

In this case, a "user friendly" location could mean one that successfully meets users expectations.

Step indicators and progress bars, given that they are usually horizontal (wide), are usually presented at the top (and, very occasionally, the bottom) center of the screen area containing the main interactions.

If you don't have a good reason not to put this element there (e.g. you have some important horizontal navigation there) you should probably embrace convention and put it top center.

Comment: Thank you su much for the explanation, as soon as I take a decision I would like to let it know.

Answer (score 1):

One option of having a progress bar is to have it act as a "sticky" bar. It could follow users while they fill out those fields. It could on the left or right side and directly display their progress.

Maybe you could have some messages at some points, if you have a really long list of forms: something like "One more to go". It still depends on your design and if you have any space left. Otherwise, go with the classical ways, by checking other websites too.

Comment: please rephrase so that your answer does not depend on the other answer. Yours should stand alone